# Why does my codenameone debug build api for Android work but release build either crashes or behaves abnormally?

Tags: codenameone

I do a debug build for my codenameone app. I can install it and it works perfectly on the device as it works on the simulator. When I make the release build, the app will install but crashes intermittently and randomly. Many functionalities do not also work as they do on the simulator.
Why? How do I find out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is because of obfuscation. You can check that by disabling obfuscation using the build hint: `android.enableProguard=false`. If this solves the problem you need to make a proper fix by using excludes properly to block obfuscation of specific things.